# Qt4.8: Why enum not seen in qmetaobject? And how to get worked?

Tags: c++, qt, enums, qt4, qmetaobject

Define of "function" I can't refactor. But need use in test class.
Used Qt 4.8. The following code return 1, but expected 2.

How to use typedef enum in test class?

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QObject>

#include <QMetaEnum>

typedef enum {
   READ  = 0x30,
   AUTH  = 0x40,
   EJECT = 0x55
}__attribute__ ((packed)) function;

class test : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  explicit test(QObject *parent = 0){
    qDebug() << "Enums count=" << this->metaObject()->enumeratorCount();
    qDebug() << "Functions=" << this->metaObject()->enumerator( this->metaObject()->indexOfEnumerator("function") ).keyCount();
    qDebug() << "worked=" << this->metaObject()->enumerator( this->metaObject()->indexOfEnumerator("worked") ).keyCount();
  }
  Q_ENUMS(function)

  enum worked{forexample};
  Q_ENUMS(worked)
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The `typedef` construct isn't necessary in C++ code, and that applies to enums outside of classes, too. But this isn't your problem; the enum has to be a member of a `QObject` subclass to be used with the metaObject, as you already tested with `enum worked`.

More details: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qobject.html#Q_ENUMS